# Provider, hot reload, variables

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, hot-reload

I feel like I am close to the solution but at the same time it seems I have tried everything.

- I want to isolate design variables - e.g., `backgroundColor` - in a specific class - e.g., `Design`;
- I want this class to be a `ChangeNotifier` to be used as a provider; and
- **Hot reload must work** - i.e., if I change the color in the code and save, I want to see the change reflected immediately.

Pretty much the code below, but I want hot reload to work - i.e., if I change the `_backgroundColor = Colors.cyan`, I want the change to be reflected. Right now it does not. Any way to make this work?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Design()),
      ],
      builder: (context, child) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => context.read<Design>().backgroundColor = Colors.green,
        child: Container(
          color: context.select<Design, Color>((d) => d.backgroundColor),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

class Design with ChangeNotifier {
  Color _backgroundColor = Colors.cyan;
  Color get backgroundColor => _backgroundColor;
  void set backgroundColor(color) {
    this._backgroundColor = color;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

So far the only thing that worked with hot reload is either having a function to directly return the color or making the variable `const` - or `static const`, if inside a class. But then neither work with provider.

Comment: why do you want to have the color constants in a provider? Are you intending to "stream" it from a database?

Comment: I want the app to dynamically respond to design changes - e.g., the user can change themes, or specific colors of a theme, and the app responds immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, I would do the following:

```
void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Design()),
      ],
      builder: (context, child) {
        final _color = context.select<Design, Color>((d) => d.backgroundColor);
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => context.read<Design>().backgroundColor = Colors.green,
          child: Container(
            color: _color,
          ),
        );
      }),
  ));
}
```

or if you don't mind watching the whole class use

```
final _color = context.watch<Design>().backgroundColor;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Elie Saad, but unfortunately with this change hot reload still does not work - i.e., if I change the color in the code and save, the change is not reflected in the view.

Comment: Sorry this didn't work, make sure that the variable you changed in the code is not being set during rebuild, otherwise it will be reset every time the state changes

Answer (score 0):

So far the only solution I have come up with is combining const and non-const structures. Something like:

```dart
class Design with ChangeNotifier {
  static const Map<String, dynamic> smap = {
    'backgroundColor': Colors.cyan,
  };

  static Map<String, dynamic> dmap = {};

  static late final Design instance;
  Future<Design> init() async {
    return instance = this;
  }

  dynamic get(String key) {
    return dmap.containsKey(key) ? dmap[key] : smap[key];
  }

  void set(String key, dynamic val) {
    dmap[key] = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And then I use it like this:

```dart
      child: Container(
        color: context.select<Design, Color>((d) => //
            d.get('backgroundColor')),
      ),
```

I have two maps of design parameters; `smap`, *static map*, defines base values for my parameters; and `dmap`, *dynamic map*, allows me to define new values during runtime. If I change `smap` values in code and hot reload, changes are reflected. If I use the `set` function to define a new value, changes also are reflected via provider. Function `get` does the final magic. Hot reload does not work if I `set` something and then try to hot reload. Perhaps I could find a workaround for that too.